# Calculate Finance Rate, Interest Amount when we have below line Fees

Tags: interest-rate, compound-interest

Since i am not from Finance and Software Developer i find it difficult to create formulaes

I have these inputs:

1. Principal Sum:
2. Interest Rate:
3. Below Line Fee:
4. Number of Payments:
5. True Rate or Flat Rate

From these parameters i need to find the following Values

1. Finance Rate:
2. Interest Amount:
3. Flat Rate:
4. Total Charges
5. Instalment Amount:

I had researched a lot but not able to find the formaule. The examples i found are either too simple or too complex. I need these formaule to write my logic.

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: This sounds like you are asking for help in your work: writing software for finance calculations, and not an issue of personal finance that you are facing.

Comment: I will give you a hint - there is no equation to solve for rate. Even a finance calculator or excel uses an iterative process to calculate the exact number.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Developing Software

Comment: @DilipSarwate I am not asking you to code i am just asking for the formaules hoping the guys here a are specialized in the finance. I now think they are not.

Comment: @Dheer There is not coding involved. Just in junior classes we have formulaes like SI = PTR/100 there will be some better formulae for the scenario i mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The equation for the payment is

[image]

This board does not support Latex (the number formatting code) so the above is an image, the code is

```
$M=P\frac{i\left(1+i\right)^n}{\left(1+i\right)^n-1}$
```

M is the payment calculated, n is the number of months or periods to pay off, and i is the rate per period. You can see that with i appearing 3 times in this equation, it's not possible to isolate to the form i=....  so a calculator will 'guess,' and use, say, 10%. It then raises or lowers the rate until the result is within the calculator's tolerance. I've observed that unlike other calculations, when you hit the button to calculate, a noticeable time lag occurs. I hope I haven't read too much into your question, it seemed to me this was what you asked.